# Backup SQL DB to Mac Desktop via SSH

Tags: sql, ssh, terminal, mysql

How do I set the path/save location inside terminal for backing up a remote SQL database via SSH? I would like to save a backup to my desktop. I'm new to SSH, but have managed to log in and interact with the DB.

I tried this, but it said there was no such file or directory.

```
mysqldump -u user -p database > /Users/Me/Desktop/backup.sql
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating the backup, use [SCP](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) to get the file.

So, to SSH:

```
ssh user@example.com
```

Then, in SSH:

```
mysqldump -u user -p database > /path/to/backup.sql
exit
```

Then, do SCP (to copy to local directory):

```
scp user@example.com:/path/to/backup.sql ./
```

Think of SSH like remote desktop; the point of SSH is to log into another computer.  The point of using SSH in the terminal is not for file transfer; it's to do something on the server.  SCP is made to copy the file from a remote location.  So use SSH to do what you need to do (here, backup the database), and then use SCP to copy the file(s).

Comment: Ok, cheers. I didn't know what I was trying to achieve wasn't possible in SSH. Thank you!